# Bundle install: Gem::InstallError: listen requires Ruby version >= 2.2.3, ~> 2.2

Tags: windows-7, bundle, chefdk

I am looking for an answer to this github issue:  https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/399

I am using Windows 7 and trying to run `bundle install`.  I am getting the following error:

```
mysys:# bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies..................................................................................................
.............................................................................................................
Using rake 11.1.2
Using addressable 2.3.8
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using httpclient 2.6.0.1
Using buff-extensions 1.0.0
Using hashie 2.1.2
Using buff-ruby_engine 0.1.0
Using hitimes 1.2.4
Using nio4r 1.2.1
Using cleanroom 1.0.0
Using minitar 0.5.4
Using retryable 2.0.3
Using buff-ignore 1.1.1
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using mixlib-log 1.6.0
Using rspec-support 3.4.1
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using semverse 1.2.1
Using molinillo 0.4.5
Using thor 0.19.1
Using ffi 1.9.10
Using libyajl2 1.2.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using highline 1.7.8
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using mixlib-cli 1.6.0
Using mixlib-config 2.2.1
Using win32-api 1.5.1
Using net-ssh 2.9.4
Using ipaddress 0.8.3
Using systemu 2.6.5
Using wmi-lite 1.0.0
Using plist 3.1.0
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using nokogiri 1.5.11
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using yajl-ruby 1.1.0
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using ruby_dep 1.3.1
Using lumberjack 1.0.10
Using nenv 0.3.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using guard-compat 1.2.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using ruby-wmi 0.4.0
Using ruby_gntp 0.3.4
Using wdm 0.1.1
Using bundler 1.12.4
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using varia_model 0.4.1
Using buff-shell_out 0.2.0
Using timers 4.0.4
Using rspec-core 3.4.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.4.1
Using solve 2.0.3
Using win32-process 0.7.3
Using win32-dir 0.4.5
Using win32-ipc 0.6.6
Using win32-mmap 0.4.0
Using win32-service 0.8.2
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using rb-fchange 0.0.6
Installing ffi-yajl 1.4.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160604-8548-n39nif.rb extconf.rb
-IC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libyajl2-1.2.0/lib/libyajl2/vendored-libyajl2/include -IC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/include -O3 -march=i686 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048
-LC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libyajl2-1.2.0/lib/libyajl2/vendored-libyajl2/lib -L. -LC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
make "DESTDIR="
generating encoder-i386-mingw32.def
compiling encoder.c
linking shared-object ffi_yajl/ext/encoder.so
c:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lyajldll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [encoder.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/gem_make.out
Using rest-client 1.6.7
Using windows-api 0.4.2
Using net-ssh-gateway 1.2.0
Using fauxhai 3.5.0
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using pry 0.10.3
Using gherkin 2.11.8
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using notiffany 0.1.0
Using berkshelf-api-client 2.0.0
Using sawyer 0.7.0
Using buff-config 1.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using mixlib-authentication 1.4.0
Using rspec 3.4.0
Using win32-event 0.6.1
Using win32-mutex 0.4.1
Installing listen 3.1.5

Gem::InstallError: listen requires Ruby version >= 2.2.3, ~> 2.2.
An error occurred while installing ffi-yajl (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install ffi-yajl -v '1.4.0' succeeds before bundling.
PS C:\Users\502620480\githubci\og_app_bp-poa-ui> gem install ffi-yajl -v '1.4.0'
Fetching: ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32
Fetching: libyajl2-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed libyajl2-1.2.0
Fetching: ffi-yajl-1.4.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-yajl-1.4.0
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for libyajl2-1.2.0
unable to convert "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/libyajl2/vendor/yajl/test/parsing/cases/invalid_utf8.json, ski
pping
unable to convert "\x92" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/libyajl2/vendor/yajl/test/parsing/cases/non_utf8_char_in_strin
g.json, skipping
Installing ri documentation for libyajl2-1.2.0
Parsing documentation for ffi-yajl-1.4.0
Installing ri documentation for ffi-yajl-1.4.0
Done installing documentation for ffi, libyajl2, ffi-yajl after 4 seconds
3 gems installed
PS C:\Users\502620480\githubci\og_app_bp-poa-ui> bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies..................................................................................................
.............................................................................................................
Using rake 11.1.2
Using addressable 2.3.8
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using httpclient 2.6.0.1
Using buff-extensions 1.0.0
Using hashie 2.1.2
Using buff-ruby_engine 0.1.0
Using hitimes 1.2.4
Using nio4r 1.2.1
Using cleanroom 1.0.0
Using minitar 0.5.4
Using retryable 2.0.3
Using buff-ignore 1.1.1
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using mixlib-log 1.6.0
Using rspec-support 3.4.1
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using semverse 1.2.1
Using molinillo 0.4.5
Using thor 0.19.1
Using ffi 1.9.10
Using libyajl2 1.2.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using highline 1.7.8
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using mixlib-cli 1.6.0
Using mixlib-config 2.2.1
Using win32-api 1.5.1
Using net-ssh 2.9.4
Using ipaddress 0.8.3
Using systemu 2.6.5
Using wmi-lite 1.0.0
Using plist 3.1.0
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using nokogiri 1.5.11
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using yajl-ruby 1.1.0
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using ruby_dep 1.3.1
Using lumberjack 1.0.10
Using nenv 0.3.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using guard-compat 1.2.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using ruby-wmi 0.4.0
Using ruby_gntp 0.3.4
Using wdm 0.1.1
Using bundler 1.12.4
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using varia_model 0.4.1
Using buff-shell_out 0.2.0
Using timers 4.0.4
Using rspec-core 3.4.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.4.1
Using solve 2.0.3
Using win32-process 0.7.3
Using win32-dir 0.4.5
Using win32-ipc 0.6.6
Using win32-mmap 0.4.0
Using win32-service 0.8.2
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using rb-fchange 0.0.6
Installing ffi-yajl 1.4.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160604-3256-1dpveon.rb extconf.rb
-IC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libyajl2-1.2.0/lib/libyajl2/vendored-libyajl2/include -IC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/include -O3 -march=i686 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048
-LC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libyajl2-1.2.0/lib/libyajl2/vendored-libyajl2/lib -L. -LC:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
make "DESTDIR="
generating encoder-i386-mingw32.def
compiling encoder.c
linking shared-object ffi_yajl/ext/encoder.so
c:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lyajldll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [encoder.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-yajl-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/ffi-yajl-1.4.0/gem_make.out
Using rest-client 1.6.7
Using windows-api 0.4.2
Using net-ssh-gateway 1.2.0
Using fauxhai 3.5.0
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using pry 0.10.3
Using gherkin 2.11.8
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using notiffany 0.1.0
Using berkshelf-api-client 2.0.0
Using sawyer 0.7.0
Using buff-config 1.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using mixlib-authentication 1.4.0
Using rspec 3.4.0
Using win32-event 0.6.1
Using win32-mutex 0.4.1
Installing listen 3.1.5

Gem::InstallError: listen requires Ruby version >= 2.2.3, ~> 2.2.
An error occurred while installing ffi-yajl (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install ffi-yajl -v '1.4.0' succeeds before bundling.
```

---

I have successfully installed `ffi-yajl`, but I still get the same error when running `bundle install`.

I am using following version of binaries.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]

$ which ruby
/c/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby

$ which gem
/c/Ruby22-x64/bin/gem

$ which bundler
/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/bundler

DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
```

Please suggest what is the issue here? We have been trying from last 2 weeks without any success.

Comment: You need to include the problem description in the question itself.

Comment: I have pasted the content from the github link and formatted it for StackExchange guidelines.

Comment: Use virtual box with Linux! Do not use horrible Windows for coding

Comment: Not sure I have anything helpful yet other than "me too".  I'm able to reproduce this on `ruby-2.4.0` installed via `rvm` on Ubuntu 16.04.  The odd thing is that `ffi-yajl`, `libyajl2` gems appear to install fine without using `bundler`.  I think the problem crops up with specifically `ffi-yajl-1.4.0`.

Comment: Here is something that may be helpful for other folks debugging this and looking for a way to reproduce.  I'm able to reproduce using `Gemfile` from Chef cookbook: `chef-rvm` at commit `d522bc2`.  Here is what I do:  `git   clone git@github.com:martinisoft/chef-rvm.git && cd chef-rvm && git checkout -b ffi-yajl-repro d522bc254f`  Then, make sure you have `rvm` installed, and use `ruby-2.4.0`:  `rvm install ruby-2.4.0 && rvm use 2.4.0@global && gem install bundler`  Create a gemset for this bug:  `rvm gemset create ffi-yajl-repro && rvm gemset use ffi-yajl-repro`  Finally, just `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ruby 2.4. Switching on ruby 2.3 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade, you can lock Listen to version 3.0.x, e.g. in your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.8'
```

That's because 3.0.x versions can be installed on older versions of Ruby, but for safety, versions 3.1 and higher are not officially tested with outdated Ruby versions.

That should fix the gem install issue, so I'm closing this.

https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/399#issuecomment-223800740